# Fluentd - Opensearch: Logs not sending to Opensearch

Tags: elasticsearch, fluentd, opensearch, opensearch-dashboards

I am new to Fluentd and Opensearch configuration.
As part of requirememt , I have to  install Opensearch and Fluentd using helmcharts. Using Output plugin configuraton in fluentd, those logs has to send to Opensearch

Both are deployed in same cluster, same namespace
Opensearch helm chart : https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/opensearch
Fluentd helm chart: https://github.com/fluent/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/fluentd  *// Here I used opensearch as the variant and output plugin type opensearch
*
First I deployed Opensearch and all pods are up and running, I can access dashboard URL, check cluster health using public url.
Second I deployed Fluentd, with host configuration of opensearch cluster and port 9200. Also added ingress.
Here also all pods are up and running and can see fluentd starts running from pod logs

*2024-03-15 09:27:59 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=12 ppid=7 worker=02024-03-15 09:27:59 +0000 [info]: #0 listening port port=24224 bind="0.0.0.0"2024-03-15 09:27:59 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0*

But I dont see any logs stats that it successfully connected to cluster or not seeing any documents in the dashboard(index). Also the ingress URL(9800 port) which configured for Fluentd also showing nothing. URL returns a blank white page only. From Fluentd PODS, it shows the output as pasted
*2024-03-15 09:27:59 +0000 [info]: #0 starting fluentd worker pid=12 ppid=7 worker=02024-03-15 09:27:59 +0000 [info]: #0 listening port port=24224 bind="0.0.0.0"2024-03-15 09:27:59 +0000 [info]: #0 fluentd worker is now running worker=0*

Am I missing something. Why its not showing as connected to cluster, or If it is connected why its not showing any documents in dashboard.

Please help.

Also how can i send a test message to fluentd from my OSD Client. Can I use my ingress URL of fluentd(If yes which port)